# Deck of Cards and Probability

Tags: combinatorics

A standard deck of $52$ cards has $13$ ranks (Ace, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$, $10$, Jack, Queen, King) and $4$ suits ($\spadesuit$, $\color{red}{\heartsuit}$, $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$, and $\clubsuit$), such that there is exactly one card for any given rank and suit. Two of the suits ($\spadesuit$ and $\clubsuit$) are black and the other two suits ($\color{red}{\heartsuit}$ and $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$) are red. The deck is randomly arranged. What is the probability that the top two cards are both Aces?

I think I should do 4/52 * 3/51 and someone tell if it's right?

Comment: What have you tried, what is your reasoning?

Comment: What's the probability that the top card is an ace?  Given that the top card is in fact an Ace, what is the probability that the second card is also an Ace?

Comment: Please show us how you got $11 / 850$

Comment: The probability that the first card is an ace is $\frac{4}{52}$. The Probability that the second is an ace is $\frac{3}{51}$. So answer is $\frac{1}{221}$ i think

Comment: yes it is thanks!